# Excel freezes/hangs after running tools references macro programmatically

Tags: excel, vba

I have this macro to automatically check 2 tools references when my team open the file to generate email. Now when the email generation works perfectly fine - the macro to open the tools reference makes everyone excel freezes/hangs and have to force quit, while it works perfectly fine on my laptop. How do I fix the code to stop the freeze/hang?

```
Private Sub Auto_Open()

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True

    Dim strGUID As String, theRef As Variant, i As Long

    strGUID = "{00062FFF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"

    On Error Resume Next

    For i = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set theRef = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.Item(i)
        If theRef.isbroken = True Then
            ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.Remove theRef
        End If
    Next i

    Err.Clear

    ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromGuid _
    GUID:=strGUID, Major:=1, Minor:=0

    Select Case Err.Number
    Case Is = 32813
    Case Is = vbNullString
    Case Else
        MsgBox "A problem was encountered trying to" & vbNewLine _
        & "add or remove a reference in this file" & vbNewLine & "Please check with " _
        & "your team!", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Error!"
    End Select
    On Error GoTo 0

    Call AddRefWDoc

End Sub

Sub AddRefWDoc()
    Dim strGUID As String, theRef As Variant, i As Long

    strGUID = "{00020905-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"

    On Error Resume Next

    For i = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set theRef = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.Item(i)
        If theRef.isbroken = True Then
            ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.Remove theRef
        End If
    Next i

    Err.Clear

    ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromGuid _
    GUID:=strGUID, Major:=1, Minor:=0

    Select Case Err.Number
    Case Is = 32813
    Case Is = vbNullString
    Case Else
        MsgBox "A problem was encountered trying to" & vbNewLine _
        & "add or remove a reference in this file" & vbNewLine & "Please check with " _
        & "your team!", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Error!"
    End Select
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Remove the ```on error resume next``` and see what error gets thrown. You also have an error handler that will always execute.

Comment: Debugging is rather hard given `On Error Resume Next` followed by `Err.Clear` *before* checking `Err.Number`. At the very least, remove `Err.Clear` and see what happens.

Comment: I think, but can't remember for sure, but try making sure your users have trusted the VBA project object model. I seem to recall this is needed for accessing the VB IDE. Here's a guide on enabling -->https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSD29G_2.0.0/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.ug_cxr.2.0.0.doc/t_ug_cxr_enable_developer_macro_settings.html

Comment: You're changing the compile-time resolution capabilities of the VBA project of `ThisWorkbook` *while it's running*: this is *begging* for troubles. Why do you think you need to modify the VBA project's references?

Comment: A VBA project that references a type library *and uses it* will not magically start compiling if you remove the missing/broken reference: if you're referencing Outlook and things break because someone isn't using the same version, then what you want to do is **late binding**, i.e. remove the Outlook dependencies from your code (e.g. declare `As Object` instead of `As Outlook.MailItem`; use the undelying values or user constants instead of e.g. `olXYZ` consts, etc.), then remove the reference to the Outlook type library.

Comment: Can it be possible that you have mixed 32bit dlls with a 64bit application ? Or maybee the other way around ? Take a look at the involved dlls to find out if they are mixed. Usually that wont work and crash the application.